# Ignore expansion in edef

Tags: expansion, programming

I would like to populate a tabular environment programmatically using an `edef`.

For simplicity, I brought a simple example:

```
\let\\=\relax
\let\hline=\relax
\edef\mmm{\hline A & B\\}
\edef\mmm{\mmm\hline C & D\\}
\edef\mmm{\mmm\hline 1 & 2\\\hline}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\mmm\end{tabular}
```

The result:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

In this example, how can I suppress expansion of `\hline` once it being used in a `edef`? I used `\let\hline=\relax` but it does not generate the expected result.

Comment: Yep, so did I and no juice – that's why I deleted it :) Just the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: Not getting a line _ought_ to be the "expected result" if you redefine `\hline` to be `\relax` !

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're absolutely right. But I'm pretty new in TeX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use `\edef` you need to reset `\\` and `\hline` afterwards, but it is typically *not* safe to use `\edef` with LaTeX input.  The second form doesn't repeatedly expand the tokens. Please always make examples complete documents, as below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{\let\\=\relax
\let\hline=\relax
\xdef\mmm{\hline A & B\\}
\xdef\mmm{\mmm\hline C & D\\}
\xdef\mmm{\mmm\hline 1 & 2\\\hline}
}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\mmm\end{tabular}

\makeatletter
\def\mmm{\hline A & B\\}
\g@addto@macro\mmm{\hline C & D\\}
\g@addto@macro\mmm{\hline 1 & 2\\\hline}
\makeatother
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\mmm\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways for appending tokens to the replacement text of a macro. The simplest one is with `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

[...]

\def\mmm{\hline A & B\\}
\appto\mmm{\hline C & D\\}
\appto\mmm{\hline 1 & 2\\\hline}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\mmm\end{tabular}
```

Without packages,

```
\def\appto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
```

and the code above will do the same.

If you want to use `\edef`,

```
\def\mmm{\hline A & B\\}
\edef\mmm{\unexpanded\expandafter{\mmm}\unexpanded{\hline C & D\\}}
\edef\mmm{\unexpanded\expandafter{\mmm}\unexpanded{\hline 1 & 2\\\hline}}
```

---

A better interface with `expl3`. When you want to define a new variable or reinitialize it, use `\apptovar*`, otherwise `\apptovar`. You can define as many variables as you want and they'll obey the normal scoping rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\apptovar}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanT{#1}
   {
    \tl_clear_new:c { l_abforce_var_#2_tl }
   }
  \tl_put_right:cn { l_abforce_var_#2_tl } { #3 }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { l_abforce_var_#1_tl }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\apptovar*{mmm}{\hline A & B\\}% initialize
\apptovar{mmm}{\hline C & D\\}
\apptovar{mmm}{\hline 1 & 2\\\hline}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\usevar{mmm}\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this is probably what OP is going after ultimately :)

Comment: Thank you. However, unfortunately I can't mark two answers as accepted.

Comment: @abforce Unfortunately you accepted the wrong one. ;-)

Comment: @abforce [egreg is teasing :)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25089322#25089322)

Comment: @egreg Excuse me! I'd rather prefer reseting `\hline` than use other approaches. However, I'm so grateful for your answer.

Comment: @abforce I was joking. However, if you're going with the `\xdef` approach, be careful that commands such as `\bfseries` or any accented character will make it fail. Don't use full expansion unless there's no other method available.